# Is there a name for a war where everyone fights everyone else?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a name for a war where everyone fights everyone else? I think that I heard the name "Kephyr" (Turkish? for the name of a war where it's all against all but I could not verify it.

Comment: There's the word [*mêlée*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/melee), but that's usually applied to more of a small-scale skirmish, as opposed to a full-fledged war.

Comment: Perhaps "total war"?

Comment: There is [_kerfuffle_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kerfuffle) similar to your word but it is a _fuss_ or _commotion_ rather than a _war_.

Answer (score 5):

"Internecine" is an adjective that carries some of that connotation. It can apply to either a conflict in which both sides suffer severe damage, or to an internal fight among factions within a group or a nation. Look it up and see if that's what you need, and choose your favorite pronunciation.

.. If you need a noun, you might try "free-for-all".

Comment: +1 more for free-for-all than internecine.

Comment: Oooooh I was all set to say 'free-for-all' but you slipped it in at the last moment. D:< (+1)